# Get one value from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm sure there's something stupid I am doing and the answer to this is very simple but all the searches I have done have dealt with looping over the array, I don't want that.

I have an ajax call that is returning a response in the form of a very simple array.  In the success function of my ajax call if I do this:

```
console.log(response);
```

The array is logged to the console as expected.  [0] => 100, [1] => 200 etc.

If I try:

```
console.log(response[1]);
```

I am expecting to get 200 but it does nothing.  I eventually want to insert the value into a redirect like this...

```
window.location.replace('index.php?id=200');
```

But all I get is "index.php?id="

Please someone put me out of my misery. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Changed the PHP to include the following:

```
exit(json_encode("id"=>$id,"message"=>$message));
```

which returned an object (not a string).

Then in the success part of the ajax function:

```
success: function(response) {
window.location.replace('index.php?id=' + response.id + '&message=' + response.message);
}
```

This... for some reason, works fine. Don't ask me why.

Comment: Maybe your response is a string?

Comment: PHP and JavaScript arrays are not the same. You'll want to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) when sending the response back

Comment: Can you post more code or a JSFiddle?

Comment: @intothev01d is right. `json_encode()` on PHP side and then `JSON.parse()` the response in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I used json_encode() in the PHP but for some reason I didn't need JSON.parse() in the javascript, the array was already coming back as an object. I will update the question to include what worked.  Does someone want to post an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of sending information to and from PHP/Javascript is with JSON.

In PHP you can use `json_encode()` to turn your array into a JSON string. Then use `JSON.parse()` in Javascript to turn the string back into an object.

If you are using jQuery for the AJAX request and don't have the `dataType` set it will automagically detect it is JSON and parse it for you, this is probably why you didn't have to.

Comment: Thanks Evilzebra (cool handle btw).  I am using jQuery for the ajax request and I do have dataType set so not sure what's going on.  In any case, it's working now.